# Adding AppCompat v7 library to non-gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am new to Android Studio. I have an eclipse Android project which I imported to Android Studio.

When I build it I get errors with AppCompat v7 library. Can someone tell me how to solve this? [This](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) tells about adding to gradle. But I want to know for non-gradle project.

Comment: Can you further clarify your problem beyond 'I get errors'?

Comment: @mccainz I get error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' and the same error for 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838253/how-to-use-androids-appcompat-theming-application-wide